# Should I recompile code base if using Spring Java Configuration instead of XML based Configuration

Tags: spring

A classical advantage of using XML files for defining Settings or Configuration parameters is that no recompilation of code base is needed. You can build your codebase once and deploy it any where by modifying the XML.

But with Spring Java based Configuration don't I loose the above advantage. Firstly is there any magical way of by passing recompilation for simple config changes ( I would guess no.. but would like to hear comments).

Having said above... what benefits does anyone get by moving to Java based configuration over XML based.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think putting configuration parameters in your Spring XML and modifying them there is a good idea either. I would put the configuration in a dedicated configuration file.

Comment: @JanVandenbosch, i agree with your response for general config stuff not related with spring.  But what I mean in fact is - if I am using spring xml based config - I can easily switch  mocktestobjects and actual objects between testing and production if using xml with out recompilation. But can I achieve the same with spring java based config I am not sure.